# How do I force hive to always create a consistent filename like 000000_0?

Tags: amazon-s3, hive

I am doing an Insert overwrite operation through a hive external table onto AWS S3. Hive creates a output file *000000_0* onto S3. However at times I am noticing that it creates file with other names like *0000003_0* etc. I always need to overwrite the existing file but with inconsistent file names I am unable to do so. How do I force hive to always create a consistent filename like *000000_0*? Below is an example of how my code looks like, where `tab_content` is a hive external table.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tab_content
PARTITION(datekey)
select * from source
```

Answer (score 0):

Better do not do this and modify your program to accept any number of files in the directory.
Each reducer (or mapper if it runs on map-only) creates it's own file. These reducers do know nothing about each other, they named during creation. Files are marked as 000001_0,000002_0. But it can be 000001_1 also if attempt number 0 has failed and attempt number 1 has succeeded. Also if table is partitioned and there is no `distribute by partition key` at the end, each reducer will create it's own file in each partition.

You can force it to work on a single final reducer (it can be done for example if you add `order by` clause or setting  `set mapred.reduce.tasks = 1;`). But bear in mind that this solution is not scalable, because too many data will cause performance problems on single reducer. Also What will happen if attempt 0 has failed and it was restarted and attempt 1 succeeded? It will create 000001_1 instead of 000001_0.